# Get Timestamp of Google Docs Notes

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I have searched the google docs api for quite some time now and am attempting to find a way to retrieve timestamp information. For example, if I make a google doc and write a bunch of stuff in it, there was a specific point in time that I wrote those notes. Perhaps this could be retrievable through the version history of the doc.

I can't seem to find any way to access this timestamp information from the google docs api reference https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest
and was wondering if anyone has dealt with this kind of thing before. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot understand about `Google Docs Notes`. I apologize for this. Is that the comments? Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @tsnakejake How did this go?

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the Drive API

Specifically the [**revisions resource**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions)

Which will return objects of this type:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#revision",
  "id": string,
  "mimeType": string,
  "modifiedTime": datetime,
  "keepForever": boolean,
  "published": boolean,
  "publishedLink": string,
  "publishAuto": boolean,
  "publishedOutsideDomain": boolean,
  "lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": string,
    "photoLink": string,
    "me": boolean,
    "permissionId": string,
    "emailAddress": string
  },
  "originalFilename": string,
  "md5Checksum": string,
  "size": long,
  "exportLinks": {
    (key): string
  }
}
```

The Docs API will get your document with the current revision ID, which you can use in parallel with calls to the Drive API.

Though getting the actual change between revisions may be more complicated. You may have to export the revision in a text format and then compare the revisions to see what has changed.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you very much. Do you think this will be useful even if someone wrote a whole bunch of text within 1 revision? For example if I go write a bunch of notes and try to separate those notes into categories depending on the time I took those notes, I think it will all appear in 1 revision and make it difficult.